# Как добавить пустой массив в массив?

Tags: c++, массивы

Как на С++ будут выглядеть следующие строчки написанные на Python:

```
bucketCount = 10
buckets = []

for i in range(0, bucketCount):
    buckets.append([])
```

Comment: В С++ не бывает пустых массивов. Если нужен какой-то эквивалент, то можно добавить пустых векторов. `::std::vector<::std::vector<::std::any>> buckets{10};`

Comment: C++ - не динамически типизированный. То есть для каждой переменной должен быть известен тип при ее создании. `bucketCount` - это, видимо, `int`. Тут все понятно. А что такое buckets? Массив массивов `int`ов?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да

Comment: Судя по https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965601/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-vector-c вопрос отпал?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat все еще актуально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычные массивы в С++ не могут менять свой размер, поэтому используем `std::vector`:

```
int bucketCount = 10;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> buckets(bucketCount);
```

Не забудьте `#include <vector>`.

Comment: А зачем удалил?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вернул. Думал, ТС уже разобрался, раз в соседнем вопросе уже вовсю `vector<vector<int>>` пользуется.